# Can we add a scalar and a vector? $a+b+\mathbf x = \mathbf y $?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm given the equation
$$
a+b+\mathbf x = \mathbf y
$$
With the vectors $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, $\mathbf y=(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ and the two scalars $a$, $b$.

Is the following correct?
As a vector equation:
\begin{align}
a+b+\mathbf x &= \mathbf y \tag 1\\
a + b + (x_1,x_2,x_3)&=(y_1,y_2,y_3) \tag 2 \\
(a+b+x_1,a+b+x_2,a+b+x_3)&=(y_1,y_2,y_3) \tag 3
\end{align}
And the vector equation as three separate scalar equations:
\begin{align}
a+b + x_1 = y_1 \tag 4\\
a+b + x_2 = y_2 \tag 5\\
a+b + x_3 = y_3 \tag 6\\
\end{align}

Also, if it is illegal, does $a+b+\mathbf x = \mathbf y$ have any meaning or is it just nonsense?

Comment: Consider vector $(a,a,a)$ and add it.

Comment: Don't do it. It is illegal.

Comment: wait..that's illegal

Comment: Who gave you this equation? Adding a scalar and a vector is ill-defined, _unless_ it has previously been explicitly stated what it means. This is definitely non-standard, and without such an explicit clarification, it is meaningless.

Comment: Wee-woo-wee-woo, the math police will come if you try illegal additions. But in all serious, you have implicitly turned $a$ *into* the vector $(a,a,a)$. It is perfectly legal to add them now but why is that the only choice? You could just as well have chosen $(a,0,0)$.

Comment: @Jam: I agree. There is nothing special about the vector $(1,1,1)$.

Comment: Regarding whether you can add two different objects in general, consider that addition is a *function*, i.e., a mapping from one specific domain set to a range set. In particular, for addition of $a+b$, both $a$ and $b$ need to be in the **same set** (or at least type-converted naturally like $1\mapsto 1+0i$). If they aren't in the same set, then $a+b$ is undefined.

Comment: "Can I add a vector and a scalar".  No.  You can not.

Comment: You can do an operation that takes a scalar and a vector as input and you can call it addition.  But you have to define what that operation is and if you call it "addition" it should somehow have to justify that it satisfies conditions that we expect "addition" to have.  I'd argue that as "addition" is assumed to be a binary operation that takes two objects of the same type so *no* operation between scalars and vectors would satisfy *me* as being "addition".

Comment: But why are you asking about adding *two* scalars?  If you can add one you can add two.  And if you *can't* add one you can't add two.  (And you can't add one.)

Comment: You have not in any sense defined what “add” means or would mean. It’s not so much about illegality as it is about making sense.

Answer (score 3):

Use notation that will be easily understood
$$
(a+b)\left<1,1,1\right>+\bf{x}=\bf{y}
$$

Comment: But only if forced at gunpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already stated that the answer is no, but I want to reinforce why this is in a formal way. The problem here is that you are viewing scalar and vector addition as the same thing, when in fact they are not. Although we use the same symbol, "$+$", for both operations, they are not the same thing because they operate on different sets. Suppose we have a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ - then scalar multiplication is an operation between two scalars that outputs another scalar. Formally speaking, $+:F\times F\to F ~ ; ~ +:(a,b)\mapsto a+b$ given some $a,b \in F.$ Vector addition takes in two vectors and outputs another vector. But we happen to use the same symbol for it because of its similarities to scalar addition. So, $+:V\times V \to V ~ ; ~ +:(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v})\mapsto \mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v}$ given some $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V.$ But trying to do $a+\mathbf{u}$ isn't defined, since we don't have any addition operators that can add elements of different sets like $?:F\times V \to V ~;~ ?:(a,\mathbf{u})\mapsto a+\mathbf{u}$. It's about as sensible as trying to add apples and oranges, so to speak.

Comment: We do have operators that can act on elements of different sets. For instance, we can multiply a vector by a scalar. So there are nuances here that you have ignored.

Comment: Ok, I meant addition operators. I'll add that in.

Comment: I mostly like this answer but think *"don't have **any** addition operators that can add elements of different sets"* is a big overstatement, especially since the asker has implicitly defined one as $+:F\times V\to V; (a,\mathbf{u})\mapsto (a+u_1,a+u_2,a+u_3)$. Maybe "have in general a unique and natural addition operator" would fit better.

Comment: Perhaps my wording is not the best. But I think the general idea is clear enough.